# App crashes when saving a dictionary object in Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to save my quiz data into firestore like so

```
db.collection("Quizzes").addDocument(data: ["Author": userEmail,
                                                    "quizTitle": quizTitle,
                                                    "quizDescription": quizDescription,
                                                    "quizDictionary": quizDictionary]) { (error) in
                                                        if let e = error{
                                                            print("There was an erorr saving the data to the Firestore \(e)")
                                                        }
```

after clicking the button that would perform this block of code my app crashes and the following error is printed

> 020-09-19 17:17:46.367783+0800 Quizzler[18001:782362] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc4cd28a1a98b5156
> 2020-09-19 17:17:46.469546+0800 Quizzler[18001:782362] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc4cd28a1a98b5156'

After doing some debugging, I found out that the `"quizDictionary": quizDictionary` part is what's causing the crash. Why is this happening? I thought that the method `.addDocument(data: )` accepts `[String: Any]`?

If it is impossible to save Dictionary object into firestore, what are some workarounds for this?

If needed, this is my dictionary's declaration
[dictionary declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJNxO.png)

Comment: I guess that keys needs to be `String`, so you can't have a `[Int: Something]`, but needs a `[String; Something]`. According to the error, and knowing that in JSON it's key must be String, it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: You can definitely save a Dictionary to Firestore. It would be helpful to know what your data actually looks (in the question!)  like instead of showing us the vars. Stating that addDocument `accepts [String: Any]?` is not quite accurate as Any would have to be one of the supported data types (as mentioned in the answers). Also, Your Int: Is a CreateQuizModel **object** which, doesn't really sound like an Int (0, 1, 2 etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey have a look here at the documentation for adding and managing data in fireStore :- https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#swift.

Quick Overview line :- Using Map or Dictionary objects to represent your documents is often not very convenient, so Firestore supports writing documents with custom classes. Firestore converts the objects to supported data types.

Update :- As mentioned in comments it does not just convert any random object into a supported type. If you throw an NSImage at it, it won't know what to do with that. Or if the object contains some other random object it won't work. It has to contain supported types only. You can refer to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) link to understand more about the supported data types.

Comment: *Firestore converts the objects to supported data types* Well, kinda. Keep in mind that it does not just convert any random object into a supported type. If you throw an NSImage at it, it won't know what to do with that. Or if the object contains some other random object it won't work. It has to contain supported types only.

Comment: Yes thanks for this I'll update my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can only read and write supported data types with Firestore:

- arrays
- booleans
- bytes
- Firestore date objects
- floating-point numbers
- Firestore geographical objects
- integers
- maps (dictionaries, with string keys and values only of these supported types)
- nil
- Firestore references
- strings

Therefore, you must convert your custom object to a format that is recognizable to Firestore which means replacing custom types with types that are primitive to the database.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types